# Error in writing unicode to file python

Tags: python, unicode

This is my first program in python and need some help in writing utf-8 data to file.

The intention is to read data from excel file and write comma seperated data to text file and below is the code I am running which is giving the below pasted error.

```
import xlrd
import csv
import codecs


wb = xlrd.open_workbook('/etl/dev/input/CustList.xls')
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(1)

file_output = codecs.open('/etl/dev/input/CustList.csv', 'w', 'utf-8')

for rownum in xrange(sh.nrows):
    file_output.write(sh.row_values(rownum))
file_output.close()
```

and here is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TestXls2Csv.py", line 20, in <module>
    file_output.write(sh.row_values(rownum))
  File "/fstools/gptools/ext/python/lib/python2.6/codecs.py", line 686, in write
    return self.writer.write(data)
  File "/fstools/gptools/ext/python/lib/python2.6/codecs.py", line 351, in write
    data, consumed = self.encode(object, self.errors)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks 
Zulfi

Tried the below

```
            row_values = [str(val) for val in sh.row_values(rownum)]
            file_output.write(",".join(row_values) + "\n")
```

It seems to work fine for one sheet of the excel but is giving the below error for the other sheet

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TestXls2Csv.py", line 12, in 
    file_output.write(",".join(sh.row_values(rownum)) + "\n")
TypeError: sequence item 8: expected string or Unicode, float foundI had initially tried using csv.writer but there is a \xa0 character in one of the cells which was causing a lot of trouble hence installed codecs and battling to get it to work.

Below is info on the excel document if that gives any insight

=== File: CustList.xls ===
Open took 3.03 seconds

BIFF version: 8; datemode: 0
codepage: 1200 (encoding: utf_16_le); countries: (1, 1)
Last saved by: u'Rajesh, Vatha'
Number of data sheets: 2
Use mmap: 1; Formatting: 0; On demand: 0
Ragged rows: 0
Load time: 0.01 seconds (stage 1) 1.86 seconds (stage 2)

sheet 0: name = u'MEMBER'; nrows = 29966; ncols = 11

sheet 1: name = u'PHYSICANS'; nrows = 1619; ncols = 19

command took 0.20 secondsPlease suggest.

Thanks Zulfi

Comment: i think the problem is that sh.row_values(rownum) is a list (row_values  Returns a slice of the values of the cells in the given row.) and not a string, so you can't pass it to write(). If you want to write all the row you should iterate each cell

Comment: How should the output file look like? Give some example.

Comment: The output should contain the data in each excel row as comma seperated columns in text file

Comment: You mixed up your question update. Did you try my new answer?

Answer (score 1):

[dciriello](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1142814/dciriello) was right, because file_output.write should take string as its arguments, but sh.row_values(rownum) return a list, that's the main reason.

here is what to do, if you want to copy a file from xls to csv.

```
import xlrd
import csv
import codecs

wb = xlrd.open_workbook('/etl/dev/input/CustList.xls')

table = wb.sheet_by_index(1)
nrows = table.nrows

with codecs.open('/etl/dev/input/CustList.csv', 'w', 'utf-8') as file_output:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(file_output)
    for i in range(nrows):
        spamwriter.writerow(table.row_values(i))
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply.
I was trying to avoid using csv.writer because I was getting the below error with csv writer
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the values to be comma-separated in your output file, you could simply change your write command to join the list of values to a comma-separated string.

But at first you have to convert every value in the list to a string, because `row_values()` is returning a list oft string and floating values.

```
...
row_values = [str(val) for val in sh.row_values(rownum)]
file_output.write(",".join(row_values) + "\n")
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  
Tried the above and this time I guess the issues pops up while placing the data in the string.  
This u'\xa0' is bugging a lot :( I wish there is a simple alternative to dump whatever character this is from excel to text file.  

`Traceback (most recent call last):  
      File "TestXls2Csv.py", line 12, in <module>  
        row_values = [str(val) for val in sh.row_values(rownum)]  
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: changed str(val) to repr(val) without having any idea of what's the difference and it worked except that the strings were single quoted and prefixed with 'u' .